# Convert JSON to string in PostgreSQL

Tags: json, postgresql

I want to convert bibtex citations stored as bibjson pulled from a single JSON data field in PostgreSQL (13.5) into proper citation strings.

One example:

```
SELECT data
  FROM citation LIMIT 1;
```

```
 {"id": 1, "note": "DOI 10.1186/s12862-017-1032-x", "type": "article", "title": "Contrasting morphology with molecular data: an approach to revision of species complexes based on the example of European Phoxinus (Cyprinidae)", "author": [{"given": "Anja",
 "family": "Palandačić"}, {"given": "Alexander", "family": "Naseka"}, {"given": "David", "family": "Ramler"}, {"given": "Harald", "family": "Ahnelt"}], "issued": {"date-parts": [[2017]]}, "container-title": "BMC Evolutionary biology, 17(1), 184"}
```

I want to convert these finally to a proper citations string as latex would. For this I started with the title. I found out that PostgreSQL has a daunting amount of functions for dealing with JSON and that I can use e.g. '->' to get one elements text.

```
SELECT 
  data->>'title' AS title
  from citation limit 1;
```

would give me then

```
"Contrasting morphology with molecular data: an approach to revision of species complexes based on the example of European Phoxinus (Cyprinidae)"
```

As a second step I wanted to get all the people and convert them to strings. And this is also where I have problems now to progress and my question arises.

```
SELECT 
  data->>'author' AS authors
  FROM citation limit 1;
```

gives me this...

```
 [{"given": "R.", "family": "Reinartz"}, {"given": "S.", "family": "Lippold"}, {"given": "D.", "family": "Lieckfeldt"}, {"given": "A.", "family": "Ludwig"}]
```

but how would I smartly condense this into a proper string like this?

```
"Reinhartz, R. Lippold S., Lieckfeldt D., Ludwig, A."
```

Or do it even smarter and get `Author XY et al` if there is more than one author?

Any help with this would be appreciated.

UPDATE:

From the hints in the comments I tried `jsonb_array_elements_text`:

```
SELECT 
  jsonb_array_elements_text(data->'author') AS author 
FROM citation LIMIT 1;
```

However this gives me e.g. only the first object in the array.

```
{"given": "R.", "family": "Reinartz"}
```

Interestingly this only happens when I query form the table. When I copy paste the array manually like so:

```
select * from json_array_elements('[{"given": "R.", "family": "Reinartz"}, {"given": "S.", "family": "Lippold"}, {"given": "D.", "family": "Lieckfeldt"}, {"given": "A.", "family": "Ludwig"}]')
```

Then this step works:

```
                 value
-----------------------------------------
 {"given": "R.", "family": "Reinartz"}
 {"given": "S.", "family": "Lippold"}
 {"given": "D.", "family": "Lieckfeldt"}
 {"given": "A.", "family": "Ludwig"}
```

OK the limit of 1 restricts to 1 element in the output being shown of course. That was the reason here. So this works:

```
SELECT 
jsonb_array_elements_text(data->'author') AS author 
FROM citation;
```

And produces:

```
                 value
-----------------------------------------
 {"given": "R.", "family": "Reinartz"}
 {"given": "S.", "family": "Lippold"}
 {"given": "D.", "family": "Lieckfeldt"}
 {"given": "A.", "family": "Ludwig"}
```

In a next step process the inner objects:

```
select 
  concat(jsonb_array_elements(data->'author')->>'family', ' ',
    jsonb_array_elements(data->'author')->>'given') AS author
  from citation;
```

Concatenates the first and family name into a single string on each row.

@Bergi posted a solution which works out pasting together the title and the authors. See in his comment or:

```
SELECT data->>'title' || ' by ' || (SELECT string_agg((a->>'family') || ' ' || (a->>'given'), ', ') FROM jsonb_array_elements(data->'author') a) FROM citations
```

With a slight modification I now ended up with the following:

```
SELECT data->>'title' || 
       ' by ' || 
       (SELECT string_agg((a->>'family') || 
       ' ' || 
       (a->>'given'), ', ') FROM jsonb_array_elements(data->'author') a) || 
       ' ' || 
       concat('(', substring(data->'issued'->>'date-parts', '(?<=\[\[)\d{4}'), ')')
       FROM citation;
```

Which also includes the date of the publication. Thanks all for you help.

Comment: For the first query, use `->>` instead of `->` for details [see the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html)

Comment: Updated the original post with that thanks.

Comment: For the array, use `jsonb_array_elements_text` in a subquery and aggregate them with `string_agg`.

Comment: But really, do you need to do this conversion in postgres with SQL?

Comment: Unfortunately I need to. I know in any programming language that would be more easy. I am already experimenting with jsonb_array_elements_text to no avail so far. I will also look into string_agg thx to you all.

Comment: Particularly: jsonb_array_elements_text gives me only the first element of the array back. I am confused.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us how you are using it

Comment: The original post has now been updated with the suggestion.

Comment: Ah, right, I missed that the array consists of objects, so don't use the `…_text` variant. I see you already did this. Now use a subquery: `SELECT data->>'title' || ' by ' || (SELECT string_agg(a->>'family' || ' ' || a->>'given', ', ') FROM jsonb_array_elements(data->'authors') a) FROM citations`

Comment: Thanks! I Tried your query as you posted it but this gives me:   a->>'given', ', ')
             
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: [Appears to need parenthesis](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=b506f1df501375773f591223b5d07e59)… I didn't know that `||` binds stronger than `->>`.

Comment: @Claas-ThidoPfaff You might want to [post your solution as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the extensive json support of PostgreSQL for example:

```
SELECT data->>'title' || 
       ' by ' || 
       (SELECT string_agg((a->>'family') || 
       ' ' || 
       (a->>'given'), ', ') FROM jsonb_array_elements(data->'author') a) || 
       ' ' || 
       concat('(', substring(data->'issued'->>'date-parts', '(?<=\[\[)\d{4}'), ')')
       FROM citation;
```

Thanks to all for your support!